# Retrieve Entity Framework Foreign Key Relationship Models automatically

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am working on a Restaurant Application. I have a restaurant model and a table model.

```
namespace Restaurant.Models
{
    [Table("Restaurant")]
    public class RestaurantModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [Column("telephone_number")]
        public int TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
        
        [NotMapped]
        public List<TableModel> Tables;
        
        public RestaurantModel()
        {
            Tables = new List<TableModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Restaurant.Models
{
    [Table("Table")]
    public class TableModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("restaurant_id")]
        [Required] [NotNull]
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
        
        [Column("available_seats")]
        public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }
        
        [Column("is_indoors")]
        public bool IsIndoors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a dependency between Restaurant and Table:
[image]

Here are the columns and keys that Entity Framework has created for me via my context:
[image]

Lastly, here's my Context class:

```
namespace Restaurant.Data
{
    public class RestaurantContext : DbContext
    {
        public RestaurantContext(DbContextOptions<RestaurantContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        public DbSet<RestaurantModel> Restaurants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TableModel> Tables { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GuestModel> Guests { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<RestaurantModel>().ToTable("Restaurant");
            modelBuilder.Entity<TableModel>().ToTable("Table");
            modelBuilder.Entity<GuestModel>().ToTable("Guest");

            modelBuilder.Entity<TableModel>()
                .HasOne<RestaurantModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

When I retrieve a restaurant, I want the corresponding tables to be retrieved inside of the TableModel List. Currently, when I retrieve a Restaurant, it will not retrieve any corresponding Tables. This makes sense to me, as I have not properly connected the relationship for EntityFramework to recognize it. I have tried to look online how to do it, consulting guides on setting up Foreign Key relationships and such. I cannot find the information I am looking for, due to a lack of basic knowledge. The answers I can find do not make sense to me because I do not understand what they are doing or how they are doing it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What ef version  and net version are you using?

Comment: @Serge Net 5.0 and EF 5.0.11

Comment: IF you're on **.NET 5.0** (= .NET "Core" 5.0) - you'll probably be using EF **CORE** v5.0.11 - right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add relations to your classes

```
    [Table("Restaurant")]
    public class Restaurant
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [Column("telephone_number")]
        public int TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
      
        public virtual ICollection<Table> Tables { get; set; }
        
    }
}

    [Table("Table")]
    public class Table
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

         
        public int? RestaurantId { get; set; }
         public virtual Restourant Restaurant { get; set; }

        [Column("available_seats")]
        public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }
        
        [Column("is_indoors")]
        public bool IsIndoors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and since you are using Net core 5+ I don' t think that you any navigation attributes or fluent APIs

Delete old migration folde and make a clean migration to db

after this you can try this code for test

```
var restourant= context.Restourants.Include(r=> r.Tables).FirstOrDefault(r=>r.Id==id);
```

it should return  a restourant with a list of tables

Comment: Hello Serge, I tried your answer. I cannot add the 'virtual' keyword to ICollection<Table> in the Restaurant Class. It states that the field cannot be virtual. When I attempted to retrieve the Restaurants, I got an error message stating: "InvalidOperationException: The expression 'r.Tables' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty')."

Comment: @shinyshark Thanks for  a feedback. I am sorry it was a typo.  Replace with  public virtual ICollection<Table> Tables {get; set;}

Comment: Thank you Serge, that worked! Is there a source where I can study why this works? I am happy for it to have worked, but I would like to know how I can do it again in the future.

Comment: You are welcome! The main article is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key